# Storage Server - 100 TB+

Tags: storage

I'm looking at ideas for storage solutions in the 70-100 TB range.

The data that will be stored will be primarily encrypted backup images for ShadowProtect.

The data needs to be processed regularly by a Window application, ImageManager which consolidates and verifies the backups. It seems that the application isn't that friendly do deal with when it has large backup repositories, so the initial thought to address this is to have its workload split across 3-4 virtual machines.

The current idea is to have a beefy storage server and DAS unit, running HyperV, carving up the pool of disks into groups via Windows Storage Spaces so that each virtual machine has its own separate allocation of storage.

The storage server, a HP Gen 9 server & DAS, with 144 TB of raw space, mostly made up of 8 TB SAS disks.

Can I get some thoughts on above?

What design alternatives could I be look?

Thanks!

Comment: call ixsystems or get a storage consultant

Comment: You can ask questions about architecture, but this is really purchasing question, the way it's phrased right now, and those aren't allowed.

Comment: There is a number of vendors who can offer you a fitting solution. If you could describe the required technologies/features in a more specific way, we could probably address it accordingly.

Comment: This isn't hard - just buy what you need - the HPE server is great, so is the IBM/Dell equivs too, you can do the same with supermicro if budgets are tight, either way there's no rocket-science involved in this, just buy it and go.

Comment: Windows -> FreeBSD, Storage Spaces -> ZFS, + Ceph ;)

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about storage with such a big amount of drives, it definitely should be a white box, since any proprietary solution will cost significantly more. Also, you will achieve great space reduction with the help of deduplication and compression. Especially if it’s in-line deduplication, in this case all similar amount of data written to the array is reduced on a fly. Storage Spaces is a great solution overall, but it lacks in deduplication and compression functionality. Splitting the workload between VMs is not so effective due to Hyper-V’s overhead, it cuts down the storage performance. It would be better to split the load on storage level instead. E.g., separate SMB shares or create few iSCSI targets. For this situation you can take a look at [NIMBLE](https://www.nimblestorage.com/) as a good and mature solution. Likewise, [StarWind Virtual SAN Free](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free) with the log-structured file system (LSFS) with inline deduplication can be an option. StarWind has few levels of cache functionality. First is RAM cache, it can work in Write-Back mode that boosts up whole RAID performance. Second one is SSD cache, which is working in the Write-Through mode and increases read IOPS. You can create one or few RAID arrays and couple iSCSI targets to speed up your environment. An acceptable choice here may be white boxed [Storage Appliance](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-storage-appliance) from StarWind. Hope it helps.